# Does temporary paper student pilot certificate expire?

Tags: faa-regulations, student-pilot

I didn't receive my plastic student pilot certificate.

Can I use my temporary paper student pilot certificate to take checkride in the USA? Does it expire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temp certificate only for solo.

The temporary student pilot certificate remains valid for a duration of 120 days from the issuance date. Solo flights are restricted to a designated geographic region, and the student pilot is prohibited from transporting passengers or cargo. It is mandatory for the student pilot to have both their temporary student pilot certificate and government-issued photo identification in their possession when flying solo.

https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.17

Comment: Good answer.  I would suggest posting a quote from the link so the answer from 61.17 is capable of standing on it's own.